# Не удается запустить mysql на Linux (Fedora)

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal, fedora

После выполнения команды:

```
yum -y install mysql mysql-server
```

зависимости все разрешены и установка была выполнена.

Далее запускаю mysql:

```
service mysql start
```

результат получаю такой:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysql.service
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
```

Будьте добры, объясните.

Comment: А если `service mysqld start`? (mysql**d**)

Comment: @Deonis тоже самое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал другую команду для запуска:

```
sudo service mariadb start
```